# Convert a set of weighted real probabilities to a set of weighted integer odds

Tags: probability

What I have:

- A set of probabilities $$\{p_1, \dots , p_n\}$$
  So that: $$\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1$$

What I want to obtain:

- An integer $$\alpha$$ and a set of integers $$\{o_1, ... , o_n\}$$ each mapped to the probability of respective index, so that
  $$\sum_{i=1}^n o_i/\alpha = 1$$

A concrete example:

1. Probabilities: 0.35, 0.30, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05
2. Integers: 7, 6, 4, 2, 1
3. Alpha: 20

I am in fact trying a way to generalize the above numbers :)

Thanks a lot in advance, hope everything is clear.
I sense I might be talking about some math concept that I might not know about.

Comment: The first thing you should consider is whether these probabilities are arbitrary, or whether they are all rational numbers (i.e. fractions like 1/2, 7/10, 3/7, 99/100, etc.). If they are all rational, write them as fractions and see where that takes you. Your concrete example would be a good place to start (0.35 = 7/20, etc.)

Comment: Do you require $o_i/\alpha = p_i$? If not, then the existence of the $p_i$ is actually irrelevant, and given any set of positive integers you will be able to find an $\alpha$ such that the given equality holds. (Hint: take the sum of the integers.) If you do require $o_i/\alpha=p_i$, then as jwimberley suggests, consider looking at $p_i$ rational.

Comment: It is unclear what the question is. But if the $p_i$ are rational, there is an integer $\alpha$ such that $\alpha p_i$ is an integer for each $i.$ You can pick $\alpha$ as the least common denominator for the $p_i.$ When the $p_i$ are not rational, you can only get approximations.